# Проверка переменной: массив или одно значение

Tags: javascript

Столкнулась с такой проблемой. Вот задание:

> Доработайте функцию `setTitleForElement` так, чтобы первым аргументом она принимала не только **1** элемент, но и набор элементов. При этом она должна сама отличать одно от другого.

К примеру, при вызове функции:

```
setTitleForElement(document.querySelectorAll('p'), 'some custom title')
```

элементам(!) `<p>` на странице должен добавиться атрибут `title` cо значением `some custom title`.

Моё решение:

```
function setTitleForElement(elem, title) {
    if (typeof elem === 'document.element') {
    }
    else if ('array') {
        for (var i = 0; i < elem.lenght; i++) {
            elem[i].setAttribute(title, title)
        }
    }
}
```

Знаю, что выражение `typeof elem === 'document.element'` неверно. Как ещё можно проверить элемент?

Comment: как вы ее вызывать собираетесь?

Comment: Олимпиада что ли идёт?

Comment: Нет) это задание на курсы)

Comment: Вызывать через console.log думаю)

Comment: я имел ввиду `setTitleForElement(document.querySelectorAll('p'), 'some custom title')` - то есть какие параметры ему можно передать

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`querySelectorAll` возвращает коллекцию элементов, поэтому в вашем случае достаточно проверить, есть ли свойство `length` у переданного элемента: если есть, то это коллекция, если нет - одиночный элемент.

```
if (elem.length == null) {
    //одиночный
}
else {
    for (var i = 0; i < elem.length; i++) {
        elem[i].setAttribute(title, title);
    }
}
```

Comment: Окей) спасибо большое за помощь!

Comment: эм, как жеж вы в объявлении цикла допустили три точки с запятой? А i не объявили? И в переменной i не ноль, а буква о? Во дела :D

Comment: @lampa, да, косяк - копипаста с оригинального поста. Кстати `i` по большому счету можно и не объявлять :-)

Comment: @Grundy, `i` нужно объявлять с `var`, поскольку нет гарантий, что не существует глобальной переменной `i`. А еще лучше использовать ES2015 и `let i` ;)

Comment: @DmitriySimushev, не _нужно_, а _можно_ ;-) по поводу `let` может быть, но пока по привычке _var_ лезет :-)

Comment: @Grundy, именно _нужно_. Это best-practice в JS. Если вместо `i` вы используете идентификатор `counter` без `var`, то переменная `counter` из более высокой области видимости внезапно примет неверное значение.

Comment: @Grundy кстати, если подходить педантично, то сравнивать надо не с `null`,а с `undefined`.

Comment: А, да, ещё должно быть `elem[i].setAttribute("title", title);`. По поводу _"//одиночный"_: можно в этом случае `elem` преобразовать к массиву из одного элемента: тогда и строка `else {` не нужна будет, и дублирования кода не возникнет. И выйдет полный и рабочий пример кода.

Comment: На практике `undefined` заменяется `null`, это еще @Shock говорил, а то, что в параметре может быть текст - в задаче об этом ни слова.

Comment: :-D Надо было одну проверку свойства писать и не было бы столько комментариев

Comment: @Regent возникает вопрос, как приравнять один элемент к массиву без условия?

Comment: @lampa, если бы `querySelectorAll` возвращал массив - то можно было бы _concat_ использовать с пустым массивом

Comment: @Grundy не прокатит.

Comment: @lampa пока кто-нибудь не решит перейти к строгим равенствам - да, можно вольготно одно на другое заменять, не задумывая о том, какое же там значение на самом деле. Почему же без условия? Я предлагаю что-то в стиле `if (elem.length == undefined) { elem = [elem]; }`. А дальше - указанный в ответе `for`.

Comment: @Grundy а для чего тут concat использовать? Собственно, [вот fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qcezdzpv/) с тем, что я, в конечном счете, предлагаю.

Comment: @Regent, чтобы без if обойтись

Comment: @Grundy да это выйдет более громоздко и непонятно, не говоря уж о лишних действиях в случае наличия `NodeList`-a. 1-2 строки экономии того не стоят. А один `if` (без `else`) вполне себе прилично смотрится.

Comment: @Regent, поэтому я и сказал: _если бы querySelectorAll возвращал массив_, было бы примерно так: `[].concat(elem)` ну и потом цикл